# MonetDB create 100.000 columns

Tags: c++, sql, monetdb

I am trying to create a MonetDB database that shall hold 100k columns and approximately 2M rows of smallint type.

To generate 100k columns I am using a C code, i.e., a loop that performs the following sql request:

```
ALTER TABLE test ADD COLUMN s%d SMALLINT;
```

where %d is a number from 1 till 100000.

I observed that after 80000 sql requests each transaction takes about 15s, meaning that I need a lot of time to complete the table creation.

Could you tell me if there is a simple way of creating 100k columns?

Also, do you know what exactly what is going on with MonetDB?

Comment: Why do you need 100K columns in a single table?  It sounds like you need to restructure your DB schema.

Comment: Well, splitting a table into two (or more) might be an alternative solution, but I would like first to understand if I can keep my data in one table. The primary key is a single column, so I don't see any specific reason why monetdb would not handle this.

Comment: Most DB's I think would choke on 100k columns in a table.  Oracle only supports 1K and MySQL only supports 4096.

Comment: If you think you need 100,000 columns in a database table, there's very likely a problem, but it isn't  that your DBMS doesn't support it.

Comment: That is why I use MonetDB. According to the info on the site "The number of columns per tables is practically unlimited. " (https://www.monetdb.org/content/column-store-features). Plus monetdb is column-oriented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use only one create table

in script shell (bash) :

```bash
#!/bin/bash

fic="/tmp/100k.sql"


col=1

echo "CREATE TABLE bigcol (" > $fic

while [[ $col -lt 100000 ]]
do
    echo "field$col SMALLINT," >> $fic

    col=$(($col + 1))

done

echo "field$col SMALLINT);" >> $fic
```

And in command line :

```
sh 100k.sh
mclient yourbdd < /tmp/100k.sql
```

wait about 2 minutes :D

```
mclient yourbdd
> \d bigcol
[ ... ... ...]
    "field99997"  SMALLINT,
    "field99998"  SMALLINT,
    "field99999"  SMALLINT,
    "field100000" SMALLINT
);
```

DROP TABLE bigcol is against very very long. I do not know why.

I also think it is not a good idea, but it answer your question.

Pierre

Comment: Well, seems that when all the columns are created during "CREATE TABLE" request then everything works fine. Thank you.